# Alternative to strtotime() in CakePHP Query

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a query in a CakePHP 2.0 application where it retrieves a list of records for a specific customer and a specific contract, and all within the last three months:

```
$jobsheets = $this->Jobsheet->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Jobsheet.contract' => $contractid,
        'Jobsheet.deleted' => '0',
        'Jobsheet.closed' => '0',
        'Jobsheet.jobdate >' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-3 month"))
    ),
    'recursive' => 2,
    'order' => 'Jobsheet.jobdate DESC'
));
```

However, this has proven problematic, and I've been asked to implement an alternative. I can write an alternative in the form of an SQL query, but I'd like to stick to CakePHP's query builder as much as I can. If this isn't possible, then I will go for the SQL route. But for now, I'd appreciate an alternative to the `date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-3 month"))` code.

Comment: Would it be better to just say -92 days? If you need exactly three calendar months then I guess youd be better off to write your own function. I understand that strtotime can be a bit flaky with +/- months.

Comment: not all 3 months would be 92 days as months have anywhere between 28-31 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$jobsheets = $this->Jobsheet->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Jobsheet.contract' => $contractid,
        'Jobsheet.deleted' => '0',
        'Jobsheet.closed' => '0',
        'Jobsheet.jobdate' => 'DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTHS)'
    ),
    'recursive' => 2,
    'order' => 'Jobsheet.jobdate DESC'
));
```

Comment: It works, but only if I write `'Jobsheet.jobdate' => 'DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTHS)'`